# Portfolio optimization using quantstrat

Tags: r, quantstrat, back-testing

I would like to backtest a portfolio of assets whose weights are mean-variance optimized.

I have seem examples [here](https://4310b1a9-a-a8fb2076-s-sites.googlegroups.com/a/r-programming.org/home/files/quantstratII.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7crzIdDyXxniq5Hq7ivmbEJdJGSVVS3HLBsjqGGcUuFu48Mli8jZ61SiSL66jVyNGgCVEFV-rlqRugvbzAbf1VKIlN4OhjhVt8Gp1hkuVg7ee2eLuEglEvrDWlTlHrqmpagPYWztv8IDObqIllAMXgtpVHZyW_0AFZQpORD4IVK5A-sy2mb1_710UUWv08j1gbF0ddWRCOE0S-88S0fDwa2R8237lA%3D%3D&attredirects=0) and [here](https://quantstrattrader.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/trend-vigor-part-iii-atr-position-sizing-annualized-sharpe-above-1-4-and-why-leverage-is-pointless/) but all the examples are either dealing with fixed orderSize/tradeSize or flexible ordersize which is computed for 1 underlying asset only. However, mean-variance algorithm compute weights for a basket of assets (allocation for any assets should depends on its relation with other assets)

My understanding is that the `osFUN` parameter in the `add.rule` function returns order size for a particular symbol. Can it return a series of weights for all symbols? If so, how should 'osFUN' be structured? In a addition, will `osFUN` be called for every symbol on every trade date or be called only once for the portfolio overall?

Any other open-source software which can tackle this issue is welcome!

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from QuantStrat blogger: "Because quantstrat isn’t applicable for that. Quantstrat is about testing signal processes on individual instruments."